# Loop through multiple columns

Tags: r, loops, for-loop

I have a dataframe similar to this one:

```
ID <- rep(c("1k", "2k", "3k", "4k"), 2)
Type <- c(rep("D",4), rep("G",4))
Values1 <- c(1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1)
Values2 <- c(0, 1, 1, 1, NA, NA, NA, NA)
dtf <- data.frame(ID, Type, Values1, Values2)
```

I want to create a loop that goes though column ID, takes the item in Values1 for all the items of Type "D" and applies it to column Values2 of the items of type "G". For instance, Values2 for 1kG should be 1 because Values1 in 1kD is 1, Values2 for 2kG should be 0 because Values1 in 2kD is 0, etc. etc.
The final dataframe should look like this one:

```
#   ID Type Values1 Values2
# 1 1k    D       1       0
# 2 2k    D       0       1
# 3 3k    D       0       1
# 4 4k    D       1       1
# 5 1k    G       1       1
# 6 2k    G       0       0
# 7 3k    G       1       0 
# 8 4k    G       1       1
```

Comment: can you be more clear with the question. it is confusing

Comment: When you used `cbind` you created a matrix, not a data frame, which is why your result as quotes around the numbers (they're now characters, not numeric). Use `data.frame` instead of `cbind` to create an actual data frame.

Comment: Try loop over the rownames/index like this..... for(idx in rownames(df)){do something to row idx}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the simple and not-very-fast implementation using a `for`-loop. How big is your `data.frame` in your real case?

```
# Initialise your example data (note I have converted to a data.frame)
ID <- rep(c("1k", "2k", "3k", "4k"), 2)
Type <- c(rep("D",4), rep("G",4))
Values1 <- c(1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1)
Values2 <- c(0, 1, 1, 1, NA, NA, NA, NA)
dtf <- data.frame(ID, Type, Values1, Values2, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

# Loop over IDs and overwrite Value2 where 
for (id in dtf$ID) {
  dtf$Values2[id == dtf$ID & dtf$Type == "G"] <-
    dtf$Values1[id == dtf$ID & dtf$Type == "D"]
}

print(dtf)
  #ID Type Values1 Values2
#1 1k    D       1       0
#2 2k    D       0       1
#3 3k    D       0       1
#4 4k    D       1       1
#5 1k    G       1       1
#6 2k    G       0       0
#7 3k    G       1       0
#8 4k    G       1       1
```

Note that it assumes that for each ID and type, you only have one record.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need for a for loop, substitution is already vectorized.

```
dtf
#   ID Type Values1 Values2
# 1 1k    D       1       0
# 2 2k    D       0       1
# 3 3k    D       0       1
# 4 4k    D       1       1
# 5 1k    G       1      NA
# 6 2k    G       0      NA
# 7 3k    G       1      NA
# 8 4k    G       1      NA

dtf[dtf$Type == "G", "Values2"] <- dtf[dtf$Type == "D", "Values1"]

dtf
#   ID Type Values1 Values2
# 1 1k    D       1       0
# 2 2k    D       0       1
# 3 3k    D       0       1
# 4 4k    D       1       1
# 5 1k    G       1       1
# 6 2k    G       0       0
# 7 3k    G       1       0
# 8 4k    G       1       1
```

Comment: Indeed, just note that this assumes the data.frame is properly sorted.